# .NET class library DLL refresh

Tags: .net

I'm using class library in .NET.

I'm generating DLL but it is being generated without the refresh file, so I can not update it automacatilly in my project.

How do you generate the refresh file with the DLL when compiling?
Or have a way to automatically update the DLL without refresh file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While adding references to a dll/library, You can add your library project as a Project reference.

This way, it will automatically get compiled/refreshed when you compile the main project.

If you are asking about getting the latest files from Source Control, before compiling then you will have to write pre/post build events.